# SQL formatar data

Tags: php, sql

Estou a fazer um SELECT com um filtro por datas, acontece que a data esta a ser guardada da seguinte forma: 20/JUN/2022 que na realidade é 20/06/2022.
Como é que posso fazer para no select ele mostrar a data assim "20/06/2022" para depois poder filtrar por data?

```
$query = "SELECT datacompra, dataVencimentocompra from $table WHERE active=1 and datacompra>= '$inicio' AND datacompra<= '$fim';";
```

Ja uso uma funçao para me identificar o mes mas nao sei como a posso usar no select.

```
function parseDate($date = null, $order = null) {
  if (empty($date)) {
    $today = date_create('now', new DateTimeZone('Europe/Lisbon'));
    $date =  $today->format("d/m/Y");
  }
  $arrayDatePayment= explode("/",$date);
  $invoiceDay = $arrayDatePayment[0];
  $invoiceMonth = $arrayDatePayment[1];
  $invoiceYear = $arrayDatePayment[2];
  $parsedMonth = "";
  switch ($invoiceMonth) {
      case "JAN":
          $parsedMonth = "01";
          break;
      case "FEV":
          $parsedMonth = "02";
          break;
      .....
      default:
          $parsedMonth = $invoiceMonth;
          break;
  }
  $newInvoiceDate= $invoiceDay."-".$parsedMonth."-".$invoiceYear;
  return $newInvoiceDate;
}
```

alguem por ai que pode ajudar?

Comment: Se a data foi guardada no banco com o nome do mês abreviado você pode tentar formatar a saída pelo próprio banco. Veja se esta resposta te ajuda https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51989749/how-do-i-convert-month-name-in-string-to-short-month

Answer (score -1):

Olá.

Julgo que deve ser isto que procuras:

```
CONVERT(data_type(length), expression, style)
```

Ou seja:

```
CONVERT(datetime, dataVencimentocompra, 103) AS dataVencimentocompra
```

EDIT: isto só para SQL Server...precisas mesmo de mySQL e aí...não dá esta solução...desculpa.

Tenta assim:

```
SELECT datacompra, dataVencimentocompra from 
SELECT datacompra, 
CASE
    WHEN dataVencimentocompra = 'JAN' THEN 01
    WHEN dataVencimentocompra = 'FEV' THEN 02
    (...)
    WHEN dataVencimentocompra = 'DEZ' THEN 12
    ELSE 00
END AS dataVencimentocompra 
$table WHERE active=1 AND datacompra>= '$inicio' AND datacompra<= '$fim';
```